# How to parse user input with regex and make new variables out of results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

The user inputs the following info into a textarea:

```
  Member[0] [U:1:189360279]  team = 0
  Member[1] [U:1:189331590]  team = 0
  Member[2] [U:1:52453166]  team = 0
  Member[3] [U:1:129146865]  team = 0
  Member[4] [U:1:187520208]  team = 0
  Member[5] [U:1:25945591]  team = 1
  Member[6] [U:1:188594831]  team = 1
  Member[7] [U:1:145357907]  team = 1
  Member[8] [U:1:116190211]  team = 1
  Member[9] [U:1:183457922]  team = 1
```

I want to extract only the long number that comes after `[U:1:` (i.e. 189360279), for each line, and then make an array out of all of the numbers that are extracted.

I tried some different expressions on http://www.rubular.com/ but am coming up short, I am not very familiar with regex.

Comment: To capture all the numbers, you can use: [`\[U:1:(\d+)]`](http://regex101.com/r/kE8zN0/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple: [`\[U:\d:(\d+)\]`](http://www.rubular.com/r/CfKTbsq08H). And then:

```
text.scan(/\[U:\d:(\d+)\]/).map { |i| i.first.to_i }
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract the long number use:

```
(?!\[U:\d+:)(?<=:)\d+(?=\])
```

[This matches the long number in capturing group 0.](http://www.rubular.com/r/zTsLMZa4oz)